# facebook graph api fetch public events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

i am new to the Facebook GraphAPI and using it via the python facebook-sdk.

What i'm trying to do is: Fetching all events from a Bandpage. Both, the Page and the Events are public.
As they are public, it should be sufficient to authorize via the app-token ("APP_ID|APP_SECRET").

Now, when i'm querying the Graph via the URL https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/punkrockhengste/events
i get an empty result set. When i generate an accessToken with the default scope (view public profile), and use it for the same query, i get two results which is correct.

That confused me obviously and therefor i tried the same thing on another bandpage https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/zaunpfahl/events . For them (and some other BandPages) i get correct results when using the app-token.

As i want to have the events on our homepage, it is no option for me to request an accessToken, because the person who viewes the page would have to grant access and so on (correct?).

edit: the only difference between the not fetchable events and fetchable events seem to be that the not fetchable ones have more than one host

Comment: I think this is because the page *punkrockhengste* did not create the events apparently.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. I can't even fetch the events itself using the id. Events from other bands, i can fetch.

Comment: Apparently it ***does*** matter, because I can pull the info for *zaunpfahl* without problems... And the only difference I found was that the events weren't created by the page for *punkrockhengste*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found the cause of the problem:
the owner has to be a person/page which allows it content to be viewed from persons of every age. if the page has set an age limit, i can't pull the informations with the app-token, as there is no information about the age.